# Ubuntu freezes in the encryption password screen when using Nvidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, freeze

We are using a GeForce GTX 1070 card with the driver nvidia driver 384.59. The OS is 16.04 LTS.

When the computer starts and I'm prompted for the password to decrypt the machine, the screen has frozen. If I start the machine in recovery mode, then resume normal boot, I can log in and use the machine.

Does anyone know why? What more info do you need to help me with this

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have secure boot enabled ?

Comment: How did you install the nvidia driver ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think I installed Nvidia Cuda now. Read that it might work. I used wget, then ran the downloaded script.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen No, secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Sounds as if the Nvidia driver is not working as you can boot to recovery mode. You should file a bug report with nvidia - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/ . Normally you would install the driver from the ubuntu repositories - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation . Not sure if Cuda has a removal script.

Comment: I've tried both cuda and normal. Benchmarked the GPU - it worked tons better with the driver than with the stock driver, even if I boot to recovery mode, and the select resume normal boot. I'll see about submitting a bug report. Thanks!